# Pandas If row value contains items from a list as substrings, save row value to a different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

If row value contains items from a list as substrings, save row value to a different dataframe.

INPUT DATAFRAME:

```
index    link
1      https://zeewhois.com/en/
2      https://www.phpfk.de/domain
3      https://www.phpfk.de/de/domain
4      https://laseguridad.online/questions/1040/pued
```

`list=['verizon','zeewhois','idad']`

If df['link'] has any item of  `list` as a substring, we need to put that specific `link` in a different new data frame.

So far, I've preprocessed the `link` column and bought to this format:

```
index    link
1      httpszeewhoiscomenwww
2      httpswwwphpfkdedomain
3      httpswwwphpfkdededomain
4      httpslaseguridadonlinequestions1040pued
```

to find which rows values contain the items from `list` as  substring 
`df["TRUEFALSE"] = df['link'].apply(lambda x: 1 if any(i in x for i in list) else 0)`

but I'm getting the error:

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not float
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use str.contains

```
list_strings =['verizon','zeewhois','idad']

df.loc[df.link.str.contains('|'.join(list_strings),case=False), 'TRUE_FALSE'] = True



 index             link                                TRUE_FALSE
    1   https://zeewhois.com/en/                        True
    2   https://www.phpfk.de/domain                     NaN
    3   https://www.phpfk.de/de/domain                  NaN
    4   https://laseguridad.online/questions/1040/pued  True
```

then just filter for True to get your new dataframe

```
new_df = df.loc[df.TRUE_FALSE == True].copy()

index               link                        TRUE_FALSE
1   https://zeewhois.com/en/                        True
4   https://laseguridad.online/questions/1040/pued  True
```

Comment: I get the following error if I use this:  `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'link'`

Comment: oh i think you need to reset your index, try using     df.reset_index(inplace=True) then
    df.drop(columns='index',inplace=True), also what do you see when you print(df.columns)?

Comment: I do not have an index column ..still, I tried what you asked..doesn't work.

Comment: does "link" show up when you print(df.columns)? You might have some hidden white spaces in your columns in which case you can try df.columns = df.columns.str.strip() to fix that

Comment: Yes , the error was due to a space right before `link`..but even that particular error isn't showing up, Im getting a new one..`TypeError: sequence item 350: expected str instance, float found`

Comment: if the column type for link is string you shouldn't be getting that error however, you can try
df.loc[df.link.str.contains('|'.join(list_strings),case=False, na=False), 'TRUE_FALSE'] = True but if that doesn't work either then try df.loc[df.link.str.contains('|'.join(list_strings),case=False, regex=False ,na=False), 'TRUE_FALSE'] = True

Comment: I thought It was because my df column contained float chars, but it was the other way round.. my comparison list had a float value at its 350th index..Thanks a bunch.:D

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to process the `link`. Can simply do something like this:

```
In [51]: import numpy as np

In [47]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[47]: 
                                                 link
index                                                
1                            https://zeewhois.com/en/
2                         https://www.phpfk.de/domain
3                      https://www.phpfk.de/de/domain
4      https://laseguridad.online/questions/1040/pued

l =['verizon','zeewhois','idad'] ## It's not nice to have variable with names like list,dict etc.

In [50]: def match(x): 
    ...:     for i in l: 
    ...:         if i.lower() in x.lower(): 
    ...:             return i 
    ...:     else: 
    ...:         return np.nan 
    ...:                     

In [48]: new_df = df[df['link'].apply(match).notna()] 

In [49]: new_df                                                                                                                                                                                             
Out[49]: 
                                                 link
index                                                
1                            https://zeewhois.com/en/
4      https://laseguridad.online/questions/1040/pued
```

Comment: in `def match():`  is l the list ?

Comment: Yes `l` is list. It's not nice to have variable with names like `list,dict` etc. So I kept it `l`.

Comment: your solution gives me an empty df even though there are stings that have substrings in the list..

Comment: Weird. I put my tested solution. It works fine in my machine. Please make sure you are copy-pasting properly.